# Laravel Events vs Service Providers

Tags: php, events, laravel, service

I'm new to laravel and I want to know what are the differences between Events and Service Providers and also when to use an Event / Service Provider. I've read the documentation but there is not much info about what is an Event nor a Service Provider.

Can someone please enlighten me?
Thank you so much!